# CSS and Internet Explorer 8/9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

This is my site where i am working on at the moment: http://www.nightcore.nl/
If you open it in ie 8 / 9 , You see that the lay-out is kinda really different from FF/Chrome
(it works good in ie 7)
I fixed the border already around the images, but it didn't solve all the problems as you can see.
I can't find where it is going wrong. Can somebody take a quick look?

Comment: Do remember to [validate your pages](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nightcore.nl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), before asking questions about layout.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a crowd sourced debugging service. If you have identified a specific CSS bug in IE, we're happy to suggest workarounds or fixes if you pose a good question. Just asking us to debug your site for you is not what SO is about.

Comment: @deceze Sorry, I am fixing all the problems I can find in the validator atm.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks I trully forgot to check it. Now I have fixed all the problems w3c gave me it works perfectly in IE. Sorry for this bad question.

Comment: No problem, but if the problem's now solved you should consider posting an answer (to help others in future) or closing the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas I posted an answer. I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do if you have many problems in IE 7/8/9/(10) when you are building your website. You should check the validator from W3C schools.

http://validator.w3.org/

Upload your file or put your website link in and fix all the errors. Mostly the comment below the errors w3c gives you are clearly helping you out.

But if it don't here is the [FAQ](http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html) from W3C.

If still problems left, than it is the time to specify your question and post it!

Comment: "the validator from W3C schools"? "W3C schools" ≠ W3C